# mknod error while trying to make a device driver file with shell

Tags: shell, awk, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, mknod

My code

```
#!/bin/sh
major=$(awk '$2=="module_dev" {print $1}' /proc/devices)
echo $major
mknod /dev/module_dev c $major 0
```

I'm practicing character device drivers, and this is one of the examples.
The code above is ought to  create a device driver file at */dev/* but there's an error that says

```
mknod: missing operand after '0'(it could be wrong because it's just a translation)
for more information type 'mknod --help'
```

This message was shown when I tried to create a device driver file (`sh ***.h`)
I have no idea what the problem is. (`insmod` is already done)

Comment: then what could be the problem? major is specified and minor is 0

Comment: Always quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific reason not to and fully understand all of the implications. Change `$major` to `"$major"` throughout your script then run it again and tell us if there's still a problem. That may not solve your problem, but until you're quoting your variables there's no point looking at it.

Comment: What is the output of the `echo $major`?

Comment: Add `set -x` after `#!/bin/sh`. My guess is that `$major` is not filled properly.

Comment: The error occurred because I left the device driver number after the first trial of mknod. I solved it by clearing the device information at /proc/devices and /dev. Anyway thanks for helping all.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this error is that `$major` has no value.  That is, `$major` is blank.

You have the echo statement there:  what does it show?  If you don't see anything, you might want to enhance it to show nothing enlightenlingly;

```
echo "major='$major'"
```

which will produce something like

```
major='213'
```

if all is well, and show empty quotes if it is working like I suspect.